# How to do INNER JOIN using a table as 'bridge' to get another value in another table?

Tags: php, mysql

Well, the title maybe confusing but this is what i'm trying to do. I have 3 tables. 2 tables as main tables and one table as the 'bridge'.

```
//table_po 
po_no     id_object     qty   price
   A1            B1       5     500
   A1            B2      10     650
   A1            B3      15     750
   A2            B1       7     450
   A3            B4       9     800

//table_pks
pks_no    id_object     tipe    qty_buy    price_buy
C1               B1      ABC       1000          600
C1               B2      DEF        500          800
C1               B3      VWX        400          700
C2               B1      GHI        800          950
C2               B3      JKL        150         1500
C2               B2      MNO       8000          250
C3               B1      PQR         50         1000
C3               B4      STU        250          250

//table_ref
no    po_no   pks_no
1        A1       C1
2        A2       C1
3        A3       C3
```

The table_ref controls which po_no should connected to which pks_no. This is my query to collect the desired output:

```
SELECT
    table_po.id_object, 
    table_pks.tipe, 
    table_po.qty, 
    table_po.price,
    table_ref.pks_no
FROM table_po 
INNER JOIN table_ref ON table_po.po_no= table_ref.po_no
INNER JOIN table_pks ON table_pks.pks_no = table_ref.pks_no
WHERE table_po.po_no = 'A1'
GROUP_BY table_pks.tipe
```

Above query, show desired rows but the data is not match. The `table_po.qty` is all `5`. If I remove the `GROUP BY` the data is redundant.

My desired output:

```
id_object     tipe     qty     price     pks_no
       B1      ABC       5       500         C1
       B2      DEF      10       650         C1
       B3      VWX      15       750         C1
```

Note:
- I prefer reliability than speed. (The data collected and displayed is normally under 100 rows)

Comment: Is that `where` clause supposed to say `WHERE table_po.po_no = 'A1'` ?

Comment: @AC yes. It's a typo. I'll edit it

Comment: Do you need to use `table_pks.id_object` to link to the correct row there?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation functions like `SUM()`?

Comment: ooh, nice @Barmar - that probably is the intent of the id_object field.  Vahn, how many "redundant" rows does the example return?  9?  (without the group_by - that's NOT helping you here)

Comment: @Barmar the id_object in table_po should exactly match id_object in table_pks. but, because table_pks has many same id_object so I create table_ref to control which po_no connected to which pks_no

Comment: @AC yes it's 9. but the redundant row of actual data may reach 1k rows.

Comment: ...so yeah, there are 3 C1 for each of the 3 A1s, so without something else to narrow it down that's expected.  Barmar's probably (hopefully) already typing up an answer, but yes, it looks like you need to further filter your results (probably on `id_object`)

Comment: @Vahn - you should create an SQL fiddle for this question.

Comment: consider using `SELECT DISTINCT` if you're having redundant data

Comment: @Lambda7 That only removes duplicates of the entire result rows, it doesn't remove duplicates of key fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `id_object` to the join condition with `table_pks`.

There's no need for `GROUP BY table_pkd.tipe`, since you're not using any aggregate functions.

```
SELECT
    table_po.id_object, 
    table_pks.tipe, 
    table_po.qty, 
    table_po.price,
    table_ref.pks_no
FROM table_po 
INNER JOIN table_ref ON table_po.po_no= table_ref.po_no
INNER JOIN table_pks ON table_po.id_object = table_pks.id_object AND table_pks.pks_no = table_ref.pks_no
WHERE table_po.po_no = 'A1'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4191c/2)

Comment: Wondering - why ? it should produce the result without id_object because we have already a 3rd relationship table.

Comment: Just to expand on the group by bit -- it's normally *dangerous* to use group by without an aggregate.  In fact, most databases won't let you do it.  MySQL's behavior is to return "a row" for each unique combination of the columns you specified, **but** there's no guarantee about which row it will pick if there are multiple results.  This makes it easy to have the query work in toy test cases, and fail "randomly" in production.

Comment: @Barmar what if in table_pks have same id_object but different tipe? Is this query reliable enough to handle that?

Comment: How should it decide which `tipe` to use if there are multiple matches?

Comment: @Farsay it'll produce more results than the OP intended, because that 3rd relationship table says that *every* `A1` in `table_po` matches up with *every* `C1` in `table_pks`.  If the `po_no` and `pks_no` were *unique* fields (such as primary keys) then you'd get at most one result for each row in your linking table, but they're not unique, so entire groups of things get matched together.

Comment: yes. that would be the issue. can I get all the tipe for the id_object, so there's two rows if table_pks has two same id_object   but different tipe

Comment: @Vahn That's what it will do. There's nothing in my query that makes it only return one `tipe`. Your `GROUP BY tipe` did that.

Comment: @AC yes now i got it. i was so much confused. there are no primary key in the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
(
select qty,price from table_po 
join
select pks_no from table_ref where pks_no='C1'
on table_po.po_no= table_ref.po_no
)
as result_1
join 
select pks_no,id_object,tipe from table_pks on result_1.pks_no=table_pks.pks_no
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL.

Comment: it is valid sql

Comment: I tried running it at sqlfiddle, it said syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
select r.po_no, r.pks_no, pks.tipe, po.qty
from table_ref r 
left join table_po po on r.po_no = po.po_no
left join table_pks pks on r.pks_no = pks.pks_no
```

Comment: All you did was change from inner join to left join. That won't make a difference if everything matches.

Comment: have run the code?

what i did is to query from table_ref then left joined table_po to get qty and left joined table_pks to get tipe

please test the query......

Comment: And you left out some columns in the `select` list.

Comment: i left out some columns so that @Vahn will get learn how my query works by adding or deleting columns..... just wanted to help out sir... and please note i am querying mainly from the reference table(table_ref) and not from table_po

Comment: add the where po.po_no = "A1"

Comment: there is no use of left join  in here.